# Simulate interceptor in Mule 4

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4

As we all know we don't have an interceptor module in Mule 4.
Currently, I have a scenario where I need to measure request and response times of an HTTP connector.
How can I achieve this? Any leads would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is not an equivalent to Mule 3 interceptors in Mule 4. One thing that you could do is to create a custom module that implements a timing [scope](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/scopes). The last version of the [JSON Logger for Mule 4](https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/api-dev/json-logging-in-mule-4/) does implement a scope that does that.

You can always just add a logger before and after the operation you are trying to measure and compare the times.

Answer (score 1):

Custom Outbound Policies can be used as interceptors if your using the HTTP module and API Manager:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/2.x/custom-policy-4-reference#outbound-policies